# Fill form input with Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to input a word to search products with Scrapy, this is the url = https://www.mercadolivre.com.br/

The problem is that I cant even pass the input form, recieving the following error:
'[scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET [https://www.mercadolivre.com.br/jm/search?as_word=&cb1-edit=smartphone>](https://www.mercadolivre.com.br/jm/search?as_word=&cb1-edit=smartphone%3E) (failed 2 times): 502 Bad Gateway'

My code is this:
`

```
class MlSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ml'
    allowed_domains = ['www.mercadolivre.com.br']
    start_urls = ['https://www.mercadolivre.com.br/']

    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={'cb1-edit':"smartphone"},
            callback=self.scrape_data
        )

    def scrape_data(self,response):
        for element in response.xpath('//li[@class="ui-search-layout__item shops__layout-item"]'):
            item = element.xpath('//li[@class="ui-search-layout__item shops__layout-item"]//h2/text()').get()
            price = element.xpath('//div[@class="ui-search-price__second-line shops__price-second-line"]').getall()
            link = element.xpath('./a/@href').get()

            yield {
                "item":item,
                "price":price,
                "link":link
            }
```

`

I believe to be passing the wrong parameters to formdata but cant figure out what is it.
I tried to use formxpath "/html/body/header/div/form" before formdata but still bad gateway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use the `FormRequest`.

Their search api is to just add the search term as the last path of the url.

for example:

```
import scrapy

search_terms = ['smartphone', 'charger']

class Mlspider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ml'
    start_urls = ['https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/' + i for i in search_terms]

    def parse(self, response):
        for title in response.xpath('//h2[contains(@class,"shops__item-title")]/text()').getall():
            yield {'title': title}
```

Ouptut:

```
...
https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Cabo Carregador Smartwatch P68 P70 P70s P70 Pro P80 Usb'}
2022-11-22 12:12:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Carregador Rápido Turbo 30w Pd Baseus Tipo-c & 2 Usb Compact'}
2022-11-22 12:12:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Carregador Turbo 20w Baseus Para iPhone 13 12 11 + Cabo 1m'}
2022-11-22 12:12:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Carregador Usb Smartwatch Relógio Amazfit Gts Mini 2e/gts 2'}
2022-11-22 12:12:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Carregador Para Relógio Amazfit Gts Gtr 42mm 47mm T-rex 1918'}
2022-11-22 12:12:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Cabo Usb-c Para Tipo-c 2 Metros Super Charge 100w Power'}
2022-11-22 12:12:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Carregador Turbo Usb + Tipo C 20w Baseus Quick Charger 3.0'}
2022-11-22 12:12:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Bateria Original Jbl Charge 3 Gsp1029102a 6000mah Greatpo'}
2022-11-22 12:12:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Cabo Carregador Smartwatch Xiaomi Mi Band 3 Usb Carga Rápida'}
2022-11-22 12:12:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Suporte Tablet Mesa Apoio Universal Videoconferência Live'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Carregador Usb Celular De Moto Universal Impermeavel Charge'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': '2 Baterias Com Cabo Carregador Para Controle Xbox One Charge'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Cabo Usb Tipo C Em L Turbo Quick Charge Gamer Mcdodo 1.8m '}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Suporte Tablet iPad Universal De Mesa Grande Resistente Pro'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Bateria Xbox One Xbox S Com Cabo Carregador Controle Charge'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Kit 10 Cabos Tipo C Android Celular Atacado Revenda'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': '44 Tomada Usb Carregador 2 Saídas Comum Van Onibus'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Kit 10 Cabos Compatível P/ iPhone Lightning Atacado Revenda'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Carregador Portátil Power Bank Magsafe Fast Charge 10000mah'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Carregador Baterias Automotivo 12v Pr10 Até 200 Amp + Brinde'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Cabo Usb Carregador Magnetico Para Huawei Band 6 Pro'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Cabo Carregador Para Smartwatch Hw12 Hw16 Hw22 Hw26 Hw26+'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Kit Play And Charge Xbox Series Bateria + Cabo Usb-c'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Tomada Usb Veicular Qc3.0 Turbo Voltímetro Aluminium On/off'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Bateira Original Jbl Charge 3 Gsp1029102a 7200mah + (brinde)'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Carregador Bateria Automotivo 2a Automático Visor Completo'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Cabo Usb Type C Para C/ Jbl Pulse 4 Flip 5 Charge 4 Jr Pop'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Carregador Bateria 12-24v Automotivo Carro Moto Caminhao 10a'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Carregador Samsung Super Rápido S21 Plus Ultra 25w'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Cabo Tubo Compativel iPhone iPad Lightning Baseus Zinco Led'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Cabo Usb Tipo C 2 Metros Fast Quick Charge 3a Trançado Forte'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Cabo Usb-c Para Tipo-c 1 Metro Quick Charge 60w Power'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Carregador Turbo Tipo C Para Samsung A20 A30 A50 A70 A80 S10'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Cabo Carregador Smartwatch Xiaomi Miband 3 Usb Relógio'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Carregador De Parede Turbo 20w Tipo-c Baseus + Cabo iPhone'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Carregador Bateria Estacionária 8ah 12v Certificado Inmetro'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Carregador Para Relógio Garmin Forerruner 245 745 935 945  '}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Carregador Turbo Quick Charge 20w Pd Ultra Rápido Duplo'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Carregador Tomada Adaptador 12v Veicular Isqueiro Carro Casa'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Kit 20 Cabos Compatível P/ iPhone Lightning Atacado Revenda'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Cabo Usb Tipo C Em L Turbo Charge Espiral Gamer 1.8m Mcdodo'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Cabo Micro Usb Reforçado 2a Fast Charge Baseus 3 Metros'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Carregador Portátil Power Bank Magsafe Fast Charge 10000mah'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Carregador Wireless Sem Fio Indução Samsung Branco Preto'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Carregador Inteligente Bateria 4-6ah Lcd Dessulfatador 12v'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Carregador De Bateria 12v Sylc Inteligente 12v Carro E Moto'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Carregador De Bateria 6a 12v Inteligente Digital P/ Carro'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Carregador Inteligente Bateria Automotivo Portatil 12v 10a'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Carregador Relógio T80 T80s T80 Pro Magnético Smartwatch Usb'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Kit 2 Cabos Usb Tipo C Quick Charge Turbo Original Baseus'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Batmax Sony 3 Np-fw50+charge Duplo A7rii/a7sii/a6400/a6500'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Adaptador De Isqueiro Para Tomada Veicular 12v Carro Energia'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Bateria Original Jbl Charge 3 Gsp1029102a 6000mah Greatpo'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Bat-eria Compatível Jbl Charge 3 Original 1 Ano De Garantia '}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/charger>
{'title': 'Carregador Samsung Super Rápido S21 Plus Ultra 25w'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone> (referer: None)
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'Samsung Galaxy M13 Dual SIM 128 GB azul 4 GB RAM'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'Samsung Galaxy A03 Dual SIM 64 GB preto 4 GB RAM'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'Samsung Galaxy S20 FE 5G Dual SIM 128 GB cloud navy 6 GB RAM'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'Samsung Galaxy A03s Dual SIM 64 GB azul 4 GB RAM'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': ' Moto E20 Dual SIM 32 GB cinza 2 GB RAM'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': ' Moto G22 Dual SIM 128 GB mint green 4 GB RAM'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': ' Moto G9 Play Dual SIM 64 GB rosa-quartzo 4 GB RAM'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'Apple iPhone 13 (512 GB) - Meia-noite'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'Celular De Idoso Multilaser Flip Vita Duo Sim 32 Mb Preto'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'Celular De Idoso Multilaser Flip Vita Duo Sim 32 Mb Dourado'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'Samsung Galaxy A13 Dual SIM 128 GB azul 4 GB RAM'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': ' Moto G41 Dual SIM 128 GB pearl gold 4 GB RAM'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'Smartphone Galaxy A03 Core 32gb 2gb Verde Samsung'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'Samsung Galaxy S21+ 5G Dual SIM 256 GB violeta 8 GB RAM'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'Smartphone Motorola Moto E22 64gb 4gb 6.5 Dual Chip Azul'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'Samsung Galaxy Note20 5G Dual SIM 256 GB verde-místico 8 GB RAM'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'Samsung Galaxy Galaxy M53 5G Dual SIM 128 GB verde 8 GB RAM'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': ' Moto G5 Dual SIM 32 GB cinza-lunar 2 GB RAM'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'Celular LG 360 Retrô Simples P/ Idosos Números Grandes Flip'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'Telefone Celular LG 360 Retrô Simples P Idosos Número Grande'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': ' Moto G22 Dual SIM 64 GB cosmic black 4 GB RAM'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'Celular Moto G20 Xt2128 Azul 64gb Mem. Interna 4gb Ram'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'Multilaser Flip Vita Dual SIM 32 MB azul 32 MB RAM'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'Xiaomi Redmi Note 10S Dual SIM 128 GB ocean blue 6 GB RAM'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'Xiaomi Redmi Note 11 (Snapdragon) Dual SIM 128 GB graphite gray 4 GB RAM'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'Realme C35 Dual SIM 64 GB glowing green 4 GB RAM'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'Xiaomi Pocophone Poco X4 Pro 5G Dual SIM 256 GB laser black 8 GB RAM'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'Samsung Galaxy A22 Dual SIM 128 GB preto 4 GB RAM'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'TCL 103 Dual SIM 64 GB power grey 2 GB RAM'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'Smartphone Tcl L7 32gb Preto'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'Telefone Celular LG Antigo Simples Para Idosos E Rural 2g'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'Samsung Galaxy A53 5G Dual SIM 128 GB branco 8 GB RAM'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': ' Moto E32 Dual SIM 64 GB rosa 4 GB RAM'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'Xiaomi Pocophone Poco M3 Pro 5G Dual SIM 128 GB power black 6 GB RAM'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'Xiaomi Redmi 10 Dual SIM 128 GB carbon gray 4 GB RAM'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'Smartphone Moto Edge 30 256gb 8gb Ram Rosê Motorola'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'Xiaomi Pocophone Poco M4 Pro Dual SIM 128 GB power black 6 GB RAM'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'Apple iPhone 13 Pro Max (256 GB) - Azul-Sierra'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': ' Moto E32 64 GB azul 4 GB RAM'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'Smartphone Galaxy S21 Fe 5g 6,4 128gb 6gb Ram Branco Samsung'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'Samsung Galaxy A52 Dual SIM 128 GB lilás 6 GB RAM'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'Samsung Galaxy A32 Dual SIM 128 GB preto 4 GB RAM'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': ' Moto G31 Dual SIM 128 GB azul 4 GB RAM'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'Asus ZenFone 8 ZS590KS Dual SIM 128 GB obsidian black 8 GB RAM'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'Positivo P26 Dual SIM 32 MB preto 32 MB RAM'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'Multilaser F Dual SIM 32 GB café 1 GB RAM'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': ' Moto E40 Dual SIM 64 GB grafite 4 GB RAM'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'Samsung Galaxy Z Flip4 5G 256 GB preto 8 GB RAM'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': 'Multilaser Vita IV Dual SIM preto'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
{'title': ' Moto G20 128 GB verde 4 GB RAM'}
2022-11-22 12:12:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/smartphone>
...
```